# Сейчас мой Брут форс подбирает все возможные пароли а как сделать так что-бы он подобрал только 6значные?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests


alphabet = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
base = len(alphabet)


n = 0
length = 0
while True:
    password = ''
    temp = n
    while len(password) < length:
        rest = temp % base
        temp = temp // base
        password = alphabet[rest] + password

    print(length, n, password)


    respounse = requests.post(
                             'http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth',
                             json={'login': 'cat', 'password': password}
                             )
    if respounse.status_code == 200:
           print('Ваш пароль:', password)
           break


    if password == alphabet[-1] * length:
        length += 1
        n = 0
    else:
        n += 1
```

Comment: Вряд ли этот код что-то подбирает, потому что внутренний цикл даже не начнёт работать. Ну и то, что это ваш код, вызывает большие сомнения.

Comment: Не нужно спамить вопросами с одним и тем же кодом. Разберитесь, какая конкретно у вас проблема, потом задайте вопрос.